# how does CLR run beginXXX in a thread pool thread?

Tags: c#

I try to figure out how CLR put asynchronous operations BeginXXX into thread pool's queue.
and which ThreadPool's API is called.
But I did not find anything when I pokeed aroud BeginRead() in System.IO.Stream
and BeginExecuteReader() in System.Data.Sqlclient.SqlCommand by Reflector 6.

Answer (score 0):

Many asynchronous operations use OS handles that have been opened for use with I/O completion ports, overlapped operations, or other OS synchronization objects that are wrapped in a managed `WaitHandle`.

In these cases, it may be that the class uses `ThreadPool.BindHandle`, or `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` instead of `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` in order to schedule an asynchronous operation for which a completion callback occurs on a thread pool thread.